# Howto get some ID for a Netty Channel?

Tags: netty

Channel.id() has been removed in Netty 4.0.0.CR9.

How do I get an ID of a Channel these days?

I used to use the id() for logging purposes in all my Handlers (E.g. System.out.println(ctx.channel().id() + " - readableBytes(): " + in.readableBytes())).

I cannot rely on the toString method of a Channel because that might be overridden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are sure that the channel is active, you can generate the unique ID of the channel by combining the `hashCode()`, `remoteAddress()`, and `localAddress()`.  Alternatively, you can simply use `Channel.toString()` which generates a string from the three properties.  If the channel is not active yet, `remoteAddress()` and  `localAddress()` will not give meaningful information, so you are still at the risk of collision.

Netty 4.1 and 5.0 re-introduced `Channel.id()`, which returns a new type called `ChannelId`.  It uses various information such as MAC address, current PID, timestamp, and hashcode, so that it can even be used as a globally unique ID. Check the [Javadoc](http://netty.io/5.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelId.html).

Comment: This is the most complete answer. Netty 4 no longer has it but you can get it by combining stuff, and Netty 5 will have it again. Thanks.

Comment: Netty 4.1 also has it.

Comment: Be careful with using Channel.toString as an id because it changes when the channel goes inactive

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/transport/src/main/java/io/netty/channel/AbstractChannel.java#L352

Answer (score 1):

You can use Channel.hashCode() . We removed id() as it was not guaranteered to be 100 % unique.

Comment: hashCode isn't guaranteed to return a unique value either, is it?

Comment: `hashCode()` isn't guaranteed to return a unique value.I would still recommend using `Channel.toString()`.  All `Channel` implementations actually rely on `AbstractChannel.toString()`.

Comment: @trustin: the toString method contains the remote address, making it unique. Can you post that as an answer? I will look at the cases where you can't retrieve the remote address once I find some time.